# Is there a way/tool to list TCP connections flaged as "thin" under Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

Is there a way/tool to list TCP connections flaged as "thin" under Linux ?

Comment: What's the definition of "flagged as thin"?

Comment: Simple - "not flagged as fat" :)

Comment: Google doesn't return anything of value for "thin tcp connection".  You'll have to be more explicit about what you're asking.

Comment: See http://www.linuxhq.com/kernel/v2.6/34-rc5/Documentation/networking/tcp-thin.txt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'thin' or what you're looking for.  Have you looked into "lsof"?